# Update list of dictionaries values based off the key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list called inventory and inside there are dictionaries for each product

```
{'productName': 'Paper', 'productDescription': 'Allows people to write 
 stuff down', 'quantity': 30,'totalReceived': 40, 'totalSales': 10}
```

I have a function that would update whatever value the user wants to, but my problem is that I dont know how to take the new value and replace the other existing value.

Thanks

Comment: if you just want to update the value of an element in a dictionary, do it like this: `inventory['quantity']=30`

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```py
inventory = [{
    'productName': 'Paper', 'productDescription': 'Allows people to write stuff down', 
    'quantity': 30,'totalReceived': 40, 'totalSales': 10
}]

def foo(product_name, key, value):
    for item in inventory:
        if item.get('productName') == product_name:
            item[key] = value

foo('Paper', 'totalSales', 20)
```